# Resources on randomized algorithms for analysis and design of quantum algorithms

Tags: resource-request, randomised-benchmarking

Are there any good resources (online courses, books, websites, etc) to study randomized algorithms that would help with an specific scope on the analysis and design of quantum algorithms?

Comment: Could you narrow the focus? I'm a bit confused if you're asking about randomized quantum algorithms or how the theory of randomized classical algorithms can inform us about quantum algorithms

Comment: I'm sorry! I may not have explained myself correctly given I am not even sure how to start. I have no expertise in randomized algorithms and I was wondering if directly going to classical books was the way to go or if there are more Quantum oriented resources. More specifically im working on designing algorithms to solve combinatorial optimization problems.

Comment: I don't think it could hurt to have background on classical strategies for combinatorial optimization. I'm assuming you're a student? If so, broader mathematical maturity is also important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Probability And Randomness: Quantum Versus Classical](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Probability_and_Randomness/YbDACwAAQBAJ) by By Andrei Yu Khrennikov is a great book on the foundations of quantum randomness. [Introduction to Random Time and Quantum Randomness](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Random_Time_and_Quantum/EYmnLvMTVLgC) by Kai Lai Chung and Jean-Claude Zambrini is another work on quantum randomness. Both these books are more focusing on the theoretical foundations of quantum randomness. MIT has also published a [recent work on quantum randomness](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/122846) by Liu, Zi-Wen.